# How to make the code more efficient in Python because this program gives time execution error for large input datasets

Tags: python-3.x

```
k = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
n,m =k
l = 0
narray = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
narray1 = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
narray2 = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
for i in range(0,len(narray1)):
    if (narray1[i] in narray):
        l=l+1
for i in range(0,len(narray2)):
    if (narray2[i] in narray):
        l=l-1
print(l)
```

The above code just does the work bare minimum but neither it is efficient nor it is working with full capacity.

How can I rebuild it efficiently?

[image: the problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively use set to check membership in O(1)

```
A = [1,5,3]
B = {3, 1}
C = {5, 7}
commonFromB = len([i for i in A if i in B])
commonFromC = len([i for i in A if i in C])
print(commonFromB - commonFromC)
```

Comment: ```commonFromB = len([i for i in A if i in B])
commonFromC = len([i for i in A if i in C])``` 
please explain me these lines, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: [i for i in A if i in B] creates a list from elements in A with filter that it only includes element if it is present in B. len() simply calculates length of this new list

Answer (score 1):

Consider using sets as pointed out by @shubham-tambere.

Also you can iterate over a map object instead of creating a list from it and then iterating over the list.  For instance:

```py
l = 0
narray = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
narray1 = map(str,input().split(' '))
for item in narray1:
    if item in narray:
        l = l + 1
```